# Performance data by school district (or by High School) in the US?

Tags: usa, government, us-census, education

I am ideally looking for data that would give me performance by public school district (or by high school) in the united states, for example:

- Average SAT / ACT Scores
- Other national test scores (e.g. for elementary school students - does this exist?)
- Graduation rates
- % of students continuing to college
- Number AP classes taken

I am also interested in secondary but related information

- Demographics
- Test scores by demographic
- Student to teacher ratio
- Average per pupil spending
- Average teacher salary
- Percent of students getting lunch assistance
- School safety (e.g. gun safety) data
- Size of school
- Program information (e.g. band, debate, mathletes, etc.)

Where can I find some (or all!) of this data?